# PDFLatex tables are covering up text

Tags: tables, pdftex

I have a series of images that I'm displaying using a table environment. However, pdflatex places my table over the references portion of my paper.

[image]

I've tried [htb!] options for the table, and it doesn't seem to make much of a difference. I've also tried to use:

```
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
```

with the [H] option, but that hasn't worked either.

Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I should also specify that this is document type is: \documentclass[iop]{emulateapj} -- which is a two column format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this just a second ago - just my luck...

[latex-fullpage picture in two column layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1856189/fullpage-picture-in-two-column-layout)

The solution is to use the figure* environment. It had everything to do with the two-column layout, and nothing to do with the image placement specifiers [htb].

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
\centering
...
\end{figure*}
```