# force figure into page width

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

I have a two columns document.
And I to force a figure into a full paper width.

I tried this:

```
\begin{center}  
 \makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{figures/reviewprocessmodel}}
 \end{center}
```

But the figure overlaps with the text.
any ideas!

Comment: use `\textwidth` not `\paperwidth` and use `figure*` for a 2-column float.

Comment: If you want the figure to occupy the width of both columns, you should use the `figure*` environment rather than the `center` environment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Want to write an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It must be a duplicate:-) I'll have a look

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yeah, you're probably right. I just remembered that I answered a similar question myself a while back ... (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165105)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I think this one is closer http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130951/pdflatex-tables-are-covering-up-text/130952#130952