# caption of the wide table not wide

Tags: captions, tabularx

I am using this code to produce a wide table, but the caption in top is still in two column format.I used \caption package but it affects all of my figures captions and never solve the problem.

```
    \documentclass[prb,twocolumn,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
    \usepackage{psfrag}
    \setlength\paperheight{11in}
    \usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amscd}
    \usepackage{psfrag}


    \begin{table}[p]
    \caption{Plots of average power dissipated $\overline P$ vs the amplitude of second         harmonic $H_{ac2}$ for different values of the relative phase $\theta$, while $m=3$,  $\alpha=0.05$ and $H_{ac1}=2 H_1$.} 
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
    \multicolumn{3}{>{\centering\setlength\hsize{3\hsize} }X}{\boldmath$m=3$\unboldmath   ,       \boldmath$\alpha=0.05$\unboldmath , \boldmath$H_{ac1}=2H_1$\unboldmath}\\ \hline
    \includegraphics[height=1.7 in,width=2.3 in]{t21.eps} & \includegraphics[height=1.7 in,width=2.3 in]{t22.eps} & \includegraphics[height=1.7 in,width=2.3 in]{t23.eps}\\ \hline
    \includegraphics[height=1.7 in,width=2.3 in]{t24.eps} & \includegraphics[height=1.7 in,width=2.3 in]{t25.eps} & \includegraphics[height=1.7 in,width=2.3 in]{t26.eps}\\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your main question, but possibly of some use for improving the code and the look of the table: (i) Since you're setting the width of the `tabularx` environment to `\textwidth`, there's no point in specifying `\centering`. (ii) You can probably dispense with the `\hline` instructions as well as the vertical bars that separate the cells, i.e., I'd write `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}XXX@{}}`.

Answer (score 5):

In a twocolumn text the `table` (and `figure`) environment only covers one column by default. The starred versions, `table*` and `figure*` cover both columns, so you want

```
\begin{table*}
..
\end{table*}
```